# Display a calculated field value in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an object Performance model in my Django project.

```
class Performance(models.Model):
   performance_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(_('Nom'), max_length=64)
   code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=16, db_index=True, default='')
   type = models.InterField(...)
   value = models.CharField(...)
```

In the Admin interface, I have a dedicated `PerformanceInlineAdmin` and a `PerformanceInlineForm` class.

In a `Performance` object, if the value field starts with "$" then the field contains  kind of `Reverse Polish Notation` expression (such as `"100 450 +"`...).
In this case, the value displayed shall be the calculated expression instead of the  field plaintext value.

But I still haven't found a reliable solution. Not even sure that it should be handled in the `Form` object.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Z.

Comment: The best way to approach this is to add a method on the model itself. `def calculated_value(self): ...` and return either `value` or the calculation if `value` starts with "$". That's part of your model's API. It shouldn't be the form's concern to know how to do this. You can then just use `performance.calculated_value()` anywhere it's needed. Then in the admin, you can just use this method as if it were a field, if you add it to `read_only_fields`.

Comment: @dirkgroten
That's interesting. But my Performance object is edited in a TabularIneline object. Therefore, any method accepting an 'obj' parameter refer to the parent class. Not the Performance class itself. How could I therefore check the 'value' fied content ?

Comment: No in `PerformanceInlineAdmin` you can do the same as in any ModelAdmin

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry, but I tried exactly what you've suggested but it does not work. I f you have anyworking code snippet, it'd be welcome.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ok, I understood what you meant. It partially works:
I've added a `get_field`in the `PerformanceInlineAdmin.readonly_fields` list.
And I've implemented properly the method `PerformanceInlineAdmin.get_value()`.
At this point it's ok.
But the trick is that if I put `get_field` in `readonly_fields`, it will by applied for every record in PerformanceInlineAdmin. If I override `PerformanceInlineAdmin.get_readonly_fields(self, obj)` the `obj` parameter does not refer to the Performance object but to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method inside your `InlineAdmin` class that returns a read-only field:

```
class PerformanceInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Performance
    fields = ['name', 'code', 'type', 'calculated_value']
    readonly_fields = ['calculated_value', ]

    def calculated_value(self, instance):
        if instance.value.startswith("$"):
            return polish_calc(instance.value.strip('$')
        else:
            return instance.value

    calculated_value.short_description = "Calculated value"
```

Note that if you define a `calculated_value()` method on `Performance` itself, you can skip the whole method in the inline admin class and just declare it in `readonly_fields`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. But the main issue of this solution is that `calculated_value`is unconditionaly in `readonly_fields`.
My requirement is: if the instance.value does not start with $, then I want to keep the field editable. 
I  eventually found a workaround but I had to implement a custom `TextInput` widget.